# Use JavaScript to count enabled checkboxes in webtable

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

below my html code

```
<table id="tblPortfolio">
<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
<tr class="even">
<td class=" sorting_1">
</td>

<tr class="odd">
<td class=" sorting_1">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkPortfolio50" onclick="Uncheck(50)" class="case" name="chkPortfolio" value="50">
</td>

</tbody>
</table>
```

from that above html
how to find input type "checkbox" is enabled or not in an specific row in that table
assume that first row with first column have an checkbox and
second row with first column checkbox not available

i want to check how many checkbox's enabled in an webtable

Comment: why does this even have a JAVA tag ? Please remove the java tag, so the area of the question cane be more specified

Answer (score 1):

> i want to check how many checkbox's enabled in an webtable

To count the enabled checkbox at webtable use following `JQuery` operation

```
var totalCheck=0;
$('table').find($('input:checkbox')).each(function() {
        if(this.checked){
         totalCheck++;
        }
 });
console.log(totalCheck);
```